# jQuery tabs - why are requests multiplying?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

Let's say I have a jQuery UI tab (ajax loaded), defined to call page abc.html. On that page I call another page, let's say def.html. In my jQuery tab definition I have defined that links within tabs should be opened within tabs, this is the definition:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $(ui.panel).undelegate('a', 'click');
        },
        load: function(event, ui) {
            $(ui.panel).delegate('a', 'click', function() {
                $(ui.panel).load(this.href);
                return false;
            });
        }

    });
});
```

Ok so this works fine when going back and forth between links in a tab. However, on my page def.html I have a button that I want to use to load the initial tab. This is how I do it:

```
$("#cancelButton").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#tabs").tabs('load', $("#tabs").tabs('option', 'selected'));
});
```

This calls my initial abc.html just fine. Problem is, when I call the link to def.html again from my newly loaded abc.html, request for def.html happens twice. I click on my cancelButton again, it redirects to abc.html, I click on def.html again and now my request is called three times and so on.

I'm guessing something somewhere gets bound multiple times, but does not get unbound. Any help would do, thanks.

Comment: No, it's <input type="submit"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out. What happened was when I called

```
$("#cancelButton").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#tabs").tabs('load', $("#tabs").tabs('option', 'selected'));
});
```

only tabsload event would fire. This means that tabsselect event was not fired before, hence links weren't getting undelegated and were bound multiple times.

What solved it was doing both undelegating and then delegating the links in tab content on load, removing any tabsselect functionality. Here's my new tab definition:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        load: function(event, ui) {
            $(ui.panel).undelegate('a', 'click');
            $(ui.panel).delegate('a', 'click', function() {
                $(ui.panel).load(this.href);
                return false;
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it is because you are calling methods on the original selector `$("#tabs")` instead of on the result of the initial call to `tabs`. Try saving the reference and using it in your cancel button handler:

```
var $tabs = $("#tabs").tabs(...);

$("#cancelButton").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $tabs.tabs('load', $tabs.tabs('option', 'selected'));
});
```